# How to get previous row value that is a mathematical argument with alias in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I got troubled in getting the getting the previous row value in the query. In the query there is a field `percent` that is a mathematical equation of `ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT userSteps.userid) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userSteps) * 100.0, 2) AS percent`

The idea is, in the `percent` field, I will get the current row and subtract to the next one and it will be the value of the `delta` field. on 1st row it should be 0 since there is no row before it. any idea?

I was planning to have `(percent - <previous of percent value>) as delta`

I tried to use `LAG()` but it got me some error of `unknown column`

```
SET @startDate='';
SET @endDate='';
SET @version='';         
WITH userSteps AS
    (SELECT ... )
SELECT  steps.version as version,
        steps.step as step,
        steps.stepDesc as stepDesc,
        COUNT(DISTINCT userSteps.userid) AS numUsers,
        ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT userSteps.userid) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userSteps) * 100.0, 2) AS percent,
        LAG(percent, 1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY steps.version
            ORDER BY steps.step
        ) delta
FROM
        (SELECT ...) steps,
        userSteps
WHERE userSteps.version = steps.version AND userSteps.maxStep >= steps.step
GROUP BY steps.version, steps.step;
```

this line that I insert got an issue:

```
LAG(percent, 1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY steps.version
            ORDER BY steps.step
        ) delta
```

I expect that it will look like this one.

```
version step    stepdesc    numUsers    percent delta
1       1       ..          10          100      0
1       2       ..          5           98       2
1       3       ..          3           92       6
1       4       ..          4           90       2
1       5       ..          8           80       10
``
```

Comment: You need an additional level of subquery or CTE.  Expressions in a `select` cannot refer to column aliases defined in the `select`.  You should also learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: got fixed, thanks for the advice. I put a subquery on it and now it works!